# One may, two verbs

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement

I wonder which of the following is grammatical.

> - Your account password or username may have changed, but hasn't yet been updated on our side.
> - Your account password or username may have changed, but haven't yet been updated on our side.

Comment: one or the other: Singular, one AND the other: Plural

Comment: I knew the or-singular and and-plural things. Here what I was not sure is that whether the `may` take effect on the second part of the sentence (thus, should be `haven't`). I didn't realize the and/or issue.

Comment: This question lacks research or even theories. As such, it is off-topic proofreading.

Comment: to @mplungjan's point and to answer your question . . . since you used "or", it implies singular so the first example would be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use only ‘or’, the verb should be singular:

> Your account password *or* username may have changed, but has not yet been updated on our side.

If, on the other hand, you leave yourself open to the possibility that both may have changed and use the ever-dreaded ‘and/or’, things are murkier. In that case, I would suggest wriggling around the problem altogether, to avoid offending more people than absolutely necessary:

> Your account password *and/or* username may have changed, but the change has not yet been propagated on our side. *(vel sim)*

Comment: so the `may` won't affect the verb on the second part of the sentence?

Comment: If you want the *"may"* to apply to the verb on the second part of the sentence you have to say either *"... but may not have been updated yet on our side"* or *"may have changed but not yet been updated on our side"*.

Comment: Thank you @Janus for this comment. This is the answer I needed.